# Working with MATLAB files on Linux server

Tags: linux, matlab

The .mat file contains several 2D arrays which need to be separated. I am working on a linux server. How do I separate them and store them as separate files?

Comment: install matlab on your linux server would be an obvious solution. however i believe there are python libraries that can parse and edit mat files

Comment: I already have Matlab installed. How do I edit the mat files?

Comment: Use `load` to get data into the workspace and then `save` to store separate files.